# pandas to_html no value representation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run the line below, the NaN number in the dataframe does not get modified. Utilizing the exact same argument with `.to_csv()`, I get the expected result. Does `.to_html` require something different?

`df.to_html('file.html', float_format='{0:.2f}'.format, na_rep="NA_REP")`

Comment: is it writing to the HTML file at all?

Comment: Yep. The numbers are rounded to two decimals. Just the NaN comes out as 'nan' no matter what I enter for na_rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `float_format` doesn't play nice with `na_rep`. However, you can work around it if you pass a function to `float_format` that conditionally handles your NaNs along with the float formatting you want:

```
>>> df

  Group    Data
0     A  1.2225
1     A     NaN
```

Reproducing your problem:

```
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> df.to_html(out,na_rep="Ted",float_format='{0:.2f}'.format)
>>> out.getvalue()

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td> A</td>
      <td>1.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td> A</td>
      <td> nan</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

So you get the proper float precision but not the correct `na_rep`. But the following seems to work:

```
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> fmt = lambda x: '{0:.2f}'.format(x) if pd.notnull(x) else 'Ted'
>>> df.to_html(out,float_format=fmt)
>>> out.getvalue()

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td> A</td>
      <td>1.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td> A</td>
      <td> Ted</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```