# How to use pandas dataframe na_rep and float_format when exporting?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

Using both `na_rep` and `float_format` on a dataframe when exporting to latex doesn't work as expected.

```py
pd.DataFrame([1.5199, None]).to_latex(na_rep='-', float_format='{:0.2f}'.format)
```

Instead of formatting the floats and replacing `NaN` with the selected string, the floats are fomatted and the `NaN` values are converted to `nan` strings.

How do you use both `na_rep` and `float_format` when exporting a Pandas DataFrame to Latex?

Answer (score 0):

The formatting function `'{:0.2f}'format` will format the `nan` values as `nan`.

Define your own formatting formatting function which handles `nan` values, just as explain in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23705133/1507124) answer for exporting to HTML.

Like so:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [1.5199, None]
).to_latex(float_format = lambda x: '{:0.2f}'.format(x) if pd.notna(x) else '-' )
```