# Different na_rep per column

Tags: python, pandas

How do I format `NaN` values differently in different columns? Say with `.to_string`. I would like some columns to use `'-'`, other columns `'?'` or just `''`. But `na_rep` only allows a single string.

Until recently, one [could](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23700835/357313) [use a formatter function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971603/357313):

```
df.to_string(float_format=lambda x: "-" if pd.isna(x) else f"{x:0.2f}")
```

Using `formatters` similarly, one could format `NaN`s in different columns differently.

However, this behavior [was](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9046) [considered](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13911) a bug and has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/36690) (pandas [1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html)).

So now that `NaN`s don't go through formatters, how do I apply different formats to `NaN`s in different columns?

Comment: I don't know if its a long shot, but I think you can "just" write your own class `NAN` that inherits `NaN` but then you overload the `__repr__` and/or `__str__` and replace all `NaN` with `NAN`

Comment: I'm afraid I would need an example, maybe as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real solution but a workaround: you could `fillna` the columns of a copy of the dataframe. This can be conventiently done for all columns in one call using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan],[1,2]], columns=['a','b'])

print(df.assign(a=df.a.fillna('-'), b=df.b.fillna('n/a')).to_string())
#     a    b
#0    -  n/a
#1  1.0  2.0

print(df)
#     a    b
#0  NaN  NaN
#1  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: That would turn the float column into `object`s, which has downsides. But the idea is great: replace `NaN` by (say) `-inf` and use `if ... else` in a formatter again!

Comment: the column types will be `object`, but the float values remain floats (verify by `.applymap(type)`), so you still can use custom formatting, e.g. `.to_string(float_format=lambda x: f"{x:0.5f}")`